# Unable to understand logic of matrix multiplication

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

Could someone guide me about concept of  parallel matrix mult using threads. I assigned one thread or process for each row of matrix. But it created too many threads for a machine with just 4 CPUs. I am unable to understand if the threads or processes are limited to a specific number say 8, how do I make each thread compute multiple rows and how do I keep track of which rows were done by which thread. Suppose I have a A[40][50]*B[50][60]. I would not want to create 40 threads. What modifications would I need in this code to have just 5 threads instead of equal to number of rows.

Comment: You're not limited to 4 threads on a machine with 4 cores, but the threads won't all run at once.

Comment: If you want to restrict your program to running only 5 threads, then create only 5 threads and have each thread calculate 10 rows.

Comment: matrix size was just an example . It has to be specified dynamically . Say 65x78 ... I am unable to write , how do I divide it among threads

Comment: Then make 5 threads and divide your output matrix into 5 blocks, and have each thread solve one block.

Comment: number of rows in one block would be dynamic :\

Answer (score 1):

Threads are not limited to a specific number based on number of available execution cores on the processor.  Look at your process monitor / task manager window - There are thousands of threads running around in dozens of processes at any given moment. Only a handful can execute at the same time, but the thread scheduler's job is to keep the CPU busy by prioritizing threads that are ready to run.

There is overhead associated with creating new threads - a fair amount of memory and system resources have to be allocated for each new thread created, so you don't want to create thousands of threads in your own process. If you have lots of little tiny tasks to be performed, you could use a thread pool to eliminate the cost of creating threads. But for your matrix use case, you don't need a thread pool.

Just decide how many threads you want to use, and divide your work into that many blocks.  If you decide to use 5 threads, then divide the number of matrix rows by 5 and tell each thread what row to start with and how many rows to consume. Don't assume every thread will be processing the same number of rows - the last block will need to finish off however many rows remain, which could be less than 5 if the total number of rows is not an even multiple of 5.

For a matrix of N rows (N determined dynamically at runtime), issue blocks of N / 5 rows to each thread, plus one block of N mod 5 to catch any remainders.  (ok, that's 6 threads, but it's ok)

Comment: Thanks , I understood it , Possibility of any example illustrating that !!